# Elements traversing across parent, z-index

Tags: javascript, css

For any element that is clicked in the stack, the target element should be assigned a higher z-index than all of those that come before it in the DOM. Then it should `translateY()` pixels up to the first element.

The desired result is for the target element to sit on top of the first element in the parent. Yet there is a bug where it makes it appear that some elements get a lower z-index . If this could be refactored better as well how could it be improved?

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

divs.forEach((div) => {
    div.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let i = 0;
        let previous_sibling = event.target.previousElementSibling;
    while (previous_sibling != null) {
        i++;
      previous_sibling = previous_sibling.previousElementSibling;
    }
    event.target.style.cssText = `
        position: relative;
      z-index: ${i + 1};
        transform: translateY(-${i * 45}px);
    `;
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 45px;
/*   border: 1px solid; */
  margin: auto;
}

section {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

div {
  transition: transform .75s linear;
}

#box1 {
  background: red;
}

#box2 {
  background: blue;
}

#box3 {
  background: green;
}

#box4 {
  background: orange;
}

#box5 {
  background: purple;
}

#box6 {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="box" id="box1">1</div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">3</div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">4</div>
  <div class="box" id="box5">5</div>
  <div class="box" id="box6">6</div>
  <div class="box" id="box1">7</div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">8</div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">9</div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">10</div>
  <div class="box" id="box5">11</div>
  <div class="box" id="box6">12</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Seems to be correct to me.

Comment: Currently each element gets the `z-index` according to its DOM position due to the use of `previousElementSibling` and a simple `counter`. This means for example that **#3** can never be above **#4** no matter which one gets clicked first. Is that behaviour desired?

Comment: Click on Box 12 followed by Box 2. Box 2 doesn't overlap box 12 when it should @JavaScript

Comment: Whatever element is clicked it needs to "sit on top" of the presiding top element. So if went ... 1, 2, 3, 4 ---> 4, 2, 3 ---> 2, 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the `z-index` gets calculated by the elements DOM position due to the use of `previousElementSibling` and the simple counter. Since `translateY` does not change the position of the elements in the DOM they can never be out of order. For example numer **#3** can never be on top of **#4** because it never is in the DOM. To change this behaviour you could simply store the highest `z-index` (here in the `dataset` of the `section`) and reuse / add to it.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

divs.forEach((div) => {
    div.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      //REM: Get the highest z-index
      let tCurrentZ = ~~div.parentNode.dataset.zindex;
    
      let i = 0;
        let previous_sibling = event.target.previousElementSibling;
    while (previous_sibling != null) {
        i++;
      previous_sibling = previous_sibling.previousElementSibling;
    }
    event.target.style.cssText = `
        position: relative;
        z-index: ${tCurrentZ};
        transform: translateY(-${i * 45}px);
    `;
    
    //REM: Increase the highest z-index
    div.parentNode.dataset.zindex = tCurrentZ + 1
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 45px;
/*   border: 1px solid; */
  margin: auto;
}

section {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

div {
  transition: transform .75s linear;
}

#box1 {
  background: red;
}

#box2 {
  background: blue;
}

#box3 {
  background: green;
}

#box4 {
  background: orange;
}

#box5 {
  background: purple;
}

#box6 {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="box" id="box1">1</div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">3</div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">4</div>
  <div class="box" id="box5">5</div>
  <div class="box" id="box6">6</div>
  <div class="box" id="box1">7</div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">8</div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">9</div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">10</div>
  <div class="box" id="box5">11</div>
  <div class="box" id="box6">12</div>
</section>
```